# How to get the most information about a connection using poll() in a port scanner

Tags: c, linux, polling

I am experimenting and making a little port scanner. After completing it with `select()` I came across the limitation of any file descriptors over 1024 causes issues. Now I have changed it to use `poll()` but I am unsure of the correct method to get the same amount of information.

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <poll.h>

void set_nonblocking(int sockfd) {
    int flags = fcntl(sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fcntl(sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) == -1) {
        exit(1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *host = "127.0.0.1";
    int stop_port = 1024;
    struct pollfd fds[1024];
    int sock;

    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host);

    for (int i = 0; i < stop_port; i++) {
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sock == -1) {
            exit(1);
        }

        set_nonblocking(sock);

        server_address.sin_port = htons(i);
        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address)) == -1 &&
            errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            exit(1);
        }

        fds[i].fd = sock;
        fds[i].events = (POLLOUT | POLLIN);
    }

    int ready_fds;

    while (1) {
        ready_fds = poll(fds, stop_port, 0);
        if (ready_fds == -1) {
            exit(1);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < stop_port; i++) {
            if (fds[i].revents & POLLOUT) {
                printf("POLLOUT\n");
            } else if (fds[i].revents & POLLIN) {
                printf("POLLIN\n");
            } else if (fds[i].revents & POLLERR) {
                printf("POLLERR\n");
            } else if (fds[i].revents & POLLHUP) {
                printf("POLLHUP\n");
            }else if (fds[i].revents & POLLNVAL) {
                printf("POLLNVAL\n");
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When I run this, it prints `POLLOUT` for every port, which from my understanding is every connection was a success? This would be wrong and I would expect more `POLLERR`.

Comment: I suggest getting replacing the `else if (...)`'s in your for-loop with just `if (...)`, so that you can see all of the bits that are getting set rather than just the first one that matches your if-conditionals.  Btw on my Mac I had to replace `for (int i=0;` with `for (int i=1;` because leaving the port-field set to zero would cause `connect()` to error with "49/Could not assign requested address".  Also I moved the `return 0` out to after the end of the while-loop.  After that change I see that I get `POLLIN` and `POLLHUP` reported on all the failed connections, which is what I would expect.